# LINQ - LEFT join

Tags: c#, .net, linq, join

This is my old code:

```
var destinctList = HoldingsList.DistinctBy(x => new { x.ClientName, x.ProductName }).Select(x => new { ClientName = x.ClientName, ClientProductName = x.ProductName }).ToList();

foreach (var item in destinctList)
{

    var clientAlias = (from ca in someContext.ClientAlias
                       where ca.Name == item.ClientName
                       orderby ca.CreationDate descending
                       select ca).FirstOrDefault();

    if (clientAlias != null)
    {
        destinctList.Where(x => x.ClientName == item.ClientName).ForEach(x => x.ClientID = clientAlias.ClientID);
    }

    ClientProductAlias clientProductAlias = null;

    if (clientAlias != null)
    {
        clientProductAlias = (from ca in someContext.ClientProductAlias
                              where ca.Name == item.ClientProductName
                              && ca.ClientID == clientAlias.ClientID
                              orderby ca.CreationDate descending
                              select ca).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    if (clientProductAlias != null)
    {
        destinctList.Where(x => x.ClientProductName == item.ClientProductName).ForEach(x => x.ClientProductID = clientProductAlias.ClientProductID);
    }
}
```

This worked perfectly, but it took to long.

Now i want to make it all work with joins. This is what i have so far:

```
(from list in destinctList
join ca in someContext.ClientAlias on list.ClientName equals ca.Name into list_client_join
from list_client in list_client_join.DefaultIfEmpty
join cpa in someContext.ClientProductAlias on new { ClientID = (long)list.ClientID, Name = list.ClientProductName } equals new { cpa.ClientID, cpa.Name } into j1
from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty
orderby list_client.CreationDate descending
orderby j2.CreationDate descending
select new { ClientID = list_client.ClientID, 
             ClientName = list.ClientName, 
             ClientProductID = j2.ClientProductID, 
             ClientProductName = list.ClientProductName }).ToList();
```

This is what i got so far, but is not returning anything. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you can start by selecting from one table, then keep joining new tables one at a time until you find the problem.

Comment: @mbeckish I did, but it is still not working... The joins seem to mess up the query... Any other advice?

Comment: @Willem - Uhhh... did you actually understand what mbeckish said?  "I did, but it is still not working" is a non-sense resonse to that comment.  If you did, at what point does it fail?  What's the problem join?

Comment: @MystereMan As soon as i add the first join, the result is 0. At the moment both the table's are empty. DestinctList have results... So, did i do the left joins correct or am i missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that your DefaultIfEmpty statements were missing parenthesis and also I think the problem is how it's handling joins to null data. I think you definitely need the `where j1.Any()` call and you might also need the `where list_client_join.Any()`.

```
(from list in destinctList 
join ca in someContext.ClientAlias on list.ClientName equals ca.Name into list_client_join 
//where list_client_join.Any ()
from list_client in list_client_join.DefaultIfEmpty() 
join cpa in someContext.ClientProductAlias on new { ClientID = (long)list.ClientID, Name = list.ClientProductName } equals 
   new { cpa.ClientID, cpa.Name } into j1 
// maybe needs the following:
where j1.Any ()
from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty() 
orderby list_client.CreationDate descending 
orderby j2.CreationDate descending 
select new { ClientID = list_client.ClientID,  
             ClientName = list.ClientName,  
             ClientProductID = j2.ClientProductID,  
             ClientProductName = list.ClientProductName }).ToList();
```

**Update:**

```
// alternate query
(from list in destinctList  
let ca = someContext.ClientAlias
            .OrderByDescending (cca => cca.CreationDate)
            .FirstOrDefault (cca => cca.Name == list.ClientName)
let cca = someContext.ClientProductAlias
            .OrderByDescending (ccpa => ccpa.CreationDate)
            .FirstOrDefault(ccpa => int.Equals(ccpa.ClientID,
                           ca == null ? -1 : ca.ClientID) && 
                          string.Equals(ccpa.Name,list.ClientProductName))
select new
{
    ClientID = ca != null ? ca.ClientID : -1,
    ClientName = list.ClientName,
    ClientProductID = cca != null ? cca.ClientProductID : -1,
    ClientProductName = list.ClientProductName 
}
).ToList();
```

Mock up using data: http://ideone.com/XEqf4

Comment: Thank for the answer Brad, but it still returns 0 results. As soon as i add the first join, the result is 0. At the moment both the table's are empty. `DestinctList` have results... So, did i do the left joins correct or am i missing something?

Comment: @Willem, looking at your original code it looks like you do NOT want to return any data if the ClientAlias or ClientProductAlias tables to not match data in your destinctList. I've [mocked up an example](http://ideone.com/XEqf4) to play with the data here to show how it returns a result. I've also updated my answer to include an alternate join method to display data not found in other lists.

Comment: Seems to work for me as well. I had big problems with left joins performance in Linq due to translation (inner join with conditions to work as left join). Got from few minutes to 5 seconds. Thanks a lot!